# Null check operator used on a null value flutter database firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, file-upload, firebase-storage

after successful login into firebase database and picking some photos to send or upload  it to the database I get this error what is the problem I don't understand wat did I wrong I even tried with late initializations even that doesn't work I uncommented the late init why im I getting this ? everything is up to date and upgraded the text upload works fine only photo upload doesn't work

The code below is includes the upload and photo picking method

```
class Taak extends StatefulWidget{

  _TaakState createState() => _TaakState();

}

class _TaakState extends State<Taak> {

  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage ref =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;

 // //  late String filePath = uploadFile(filePath) as String;
 //  // String filePath = "IMG_7337.HEIC";
 //  String? downloadURL;
 //
 //    Future uploadfoto() async {
 //      try {
 //         Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("gs://cameratest2-41782.appspot.com");
 //            await ref.putFile(image!);
 //            downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
 //            print(downloadURL);
 //            //then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
 //        } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
 //          e.code == 'wat miss gegaan';
 //        }

    //     await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("fotos")".putFile(fileToUpload)";
    //         // .then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
    //     } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    //       e.code == 'wat miss gegaan';
    //     }
    // // File file = File(filePath);
    // // assert(file.absolute.existsSync());
    //
    //   firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("fotos").putFile(image!);
    //     // .then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
    //
    //   // uploadFile(filePath).then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
  //
  // String? downloadURL;


  Future uploadfoto() async {
    firebase_storage.Reference ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref().child('images');
        await ref.putFile(image!);
  }


 File? image;
 final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

// photo picking method from the gallery 
Future pickImage() async {
    final pick = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pick != null) {
        image = File(pick.path);
      }
      else {
        print(Error);
      }
    });

  var TaakBeschrijving = "";
  var TaakOplossing = "";

  // text string mothde om text naar de database te sturen
  Future<void> uploadText() async {
    String dataUrl = 'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==';

    try {
      await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref('uploads/').child(TaakBeschrijving).child(TaakOplossing)
          .putString(dataUrl, format: firebase_storage.PutStringFormat.dataUrl,);
    } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
```

Comment: Which line is causing error?

Comment: await ref.putFile(image!); this line in uploadfoto methode when I try to send it to the database firebase

Comment: Are you sure that you have some value in image variable?

Comment: I don't understand you what do you mean about the value ? do you mean that File? image;  ?

Comment: The error is because your image variable does not have any value means it's null

Comment: I know that but how could I resolve this do you maybe have any suggestion ?